# Scorlling filed is empty but it display some string why?

Tags: livecode

I have two Scrolling field and one containing some text and another containing some words. eg. (s1:s2) separated by colon my objective is to find how many words in the second Scrolling are appearing in first Scrolling field. (eg: if s1 is appearing in first scrolling field then it shows s1,1 it means s1 appearing one time). While executing my code it's work but if my first scrolling field is empty it shows some text also some times it takes some words in the first field. (eg:\documentclass)this word is not in 2'nd field.

I am using the following code.

```
global ar
global sam
on mouseUp
   --set the caseSensitive to true
   put 0 into tmp
   put empty into sam
   put the field SRText into myArrayT
   split myArrayT by CR
   put the number of lines of (the keys of myArrayT) into myArrayl
      repeat for each key j in myArrayT
      put  myArrayT[j] into k 
      split k by colon


      put k[1] into searchStr1
      put the field "MytextField" into sss
      repeat for each word ass in sss
         if ass contains  searchStr1 then
            add 1 to tmp
            put ass & CR & CR after sam 
            put sam into ar
         end if
      end repeat


   end repeat
   answer sam
   answer tmp
   --answer sa
end mouseUP
on mouseDown
   answer ar
   put ar into ss
      get ss 
  repeat for each word tWord in it
  add 1 to wordCount[tword]
 end repeat
 combine wordCount by return and comma
 answer wordCount
 --put empty into sam
end mouseDown
```

Comment: It might help if you added punctuation to your question.

Comment: Sorry Mark  it's because I am bad in English language

Comment: Thanks for updating your question. I'm sure it is easier to answer now. I'll give it a try as soon as I have a little time, or maybe someone else will, meanwhile.

Comment: You start off your mouseUp handler by ensuring sam is empty but you don't do the same with ar, which will report it's current contents the next time mouseDown gets called...

Comment: It would be useful if you added a sample (not: example) of the actual data used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should use quotes around field names. I promise you'll realise some day, that you have been shooting yourself in the foot all the time.

Don't use `the` in front of object references,

```
field "Field Name"
button "Field name"
```

but do use `the` in front of property references:

```
the number of lines of fld "Field Name"
the text of fld "Field Name"
the name of this stack
```

There really use no reason for your obsession with arrays. Stop using arrays when you don't need them! It just makes things overly complicated and slow.

I have modifed your mouseUp handler. I didn't look at your mouseDown handler. I believe your mouseUp handler should look like this:

```
on mouseUp
     --set the caseSensitive to true
     put 0 into tmp
     put empty into sam
     repeat for each line k in fld "SRText"
          set the itemDel to colon
          put item 1 of k into searchStr1
          repeat for each word ass in field "MytextField"
               if ass contains searchStr1 then
                    add 1 to tmp
                    put ass & colon & tmp & cr after sam
               end if
          end repeat
          put 0 into tmp
     end repeat
     put sam
end mouseUp
```

The script above is based on your approach and I really don't understand why you would do it this way and what you would do with the result. The script below is probably much more efficient and it seems more useful to me.

```
on mouseUp
     // I assume fld SRText contains a list similar to
     // "abc:1" & cr & "bcd:2" & cr & "cde:1" & cr & "def:4"
     put fld "SRText" into myData
     split myData by cr and colon
     put the keys of myData into myData
     // myData is not an array!
     repeat for each word myWord in fld "MytextField"
          if myWord is among the lines of myData then
               // use an array to store data, not to loop through
               if myCounts[myWord] is empty then
                    put 1 into myCounts[myWord]
               else
                    add 1 to myCounts[myWord]
               end if
          end if
     end repeat
     combine myCounts by cr and colon
     put myCounts
end mouseUp
```

Comment: Just let me know if this isn't what you're looking for.

Comment: you are the real LiveCode programmer

Comment: How to get the data after colon in your above example(abc:1" & cr & "bcd:2" & cr & "cde:1" & cr & "def:4)  "myData" contains abc, bcd , cde now i want the datas such as 1,2,1,4 is it possible